# Wordpress - Magic Fields - Sort by custom magic field using WP_Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using magic fields and have defined a custom post type called `collection` with a field called `sort`, where I input a number I would like to sort the custom posts by.

My WP_Query arguments is simply:

```
'post_type' => 'collection',
'meta_key' => 'sort',
'order_by' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
```

Which, upon using print_r on the $query result reveals the following mysql statement:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'collection' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'sort' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

So I am confused why the generated mysql still contains `ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date` when I am explicitly stating it should sort by `wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'sort'` and its corresponding `meta_value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'post_type' => 'collection',
'meta_key' => 'sort',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
```

order_by = orderby

Also it's not called magic fields but custom fields

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Ah thank you so much, you were right, `orderby` is correct. Just to clarify though, I meant 'magic fields' as in the [wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields/) Also, just a note, since my `sort` field was numeric, I also needed to use `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` and everything works perfectly now!